# implement order by case with paginator in cakephp

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, pagination

I'm trying to use a CASE operator in my ORDER BY clause.

The following won't work (the ORDER BY clause is ignored):

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'order' => array("CASE
                WHEN Transaction.created IS NOT NULL THEN Transaction.created
                WHEN Transaction.created IS NULL THEN Query.created
            END DESC")
    );
```

(while the following would go fine:)

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'order' => array('Query.created' => 'desc'),
    );
```

any way to implement MySQL CASE in native CakePHP 2.4 find methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try creating a virtual field (assuming you are paginating `Transaction`)

```
$this->Transaction->virtualFields['my_created'] = "CASE
                WHEN Transaction.created IS NOT NULL THEN Transaction.created
                WHEN Transaction.created IS NULL THEN Query.created
            END";

$this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'order' => array('Transaction.my_created' => 'desc'),
    );
```